# Unable to print debug statements in the file

Tags: java

I am using `log4j` in my java application to log the messages.`log4j-1.2.17.jar` is the jar file used. Below is the log file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

        <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
            <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                 <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
            <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
            <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
            <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
            <param name="file" value="D/logs/projectLog.log"/>
            <param name="append" value="true" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="info"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I am using above log file in my application. Log file got generated successfuly but in the log file , debug messages are not getting printed.

In my java class,below are the statements i have included.

```
LOGGER.info("In TestMVCController, logger info");
System.out.println("is debug enabled" +  LOGGER.isDebugEnabled());//always false even when server is started in debug mode
LOGGER.debug("In TestMVCController, logger debug");
LOGGER.error("In TestMVCController, logger errror");
```

In my log file, I can see only info and error messages being printed. In which scenario does the debug statements print and how can i make my log statements to print debug statements?Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Check your logging.properties file. There you can set the logging level to DEBUG.

Comment: In the fileAppender xml blurb above, the "Threshold" param is set twice. One sets it to INFO and the other to debug.  Maybe the "INFO" is overriding the "debug"?

Comment: @MonicaGranbois - That was my trial, initially i have used only once, stil i cannot see debug messages printed in the log file.

Comment: Try DEBUG or TRACE with uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Change the root's priority value from "info" to "debug":

```
<root>
    <priority value="debug"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>
```

This will configure the root logger to send log messages at level "DEBUG" or higher to the appender "fileAppender".  The "fileAppender" can then set the threshold it wants to log (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING etc).

Note: The appender's "threshold" parameter is optional.  If you omit it, the appender will log at the level defined by the root logger.  The "threshold" can be used if there are multiple appenders.  For example: DEBUG for a console appender and INFO for a file appender.